# make a list of objects with lists and search for items in the objects list (python)

Tags: python, list, object

I am trying to read from a text file and make a list of objects : 
The objects will contain strings and lists of strings and then I need to check if a certain string is in my objects list. I keep getting the error can't covert list to string even though I put str in front of it or make a def  **str** in my class.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post the code you're having trouble with in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear what you are looking for exactly, but here is an example of creating a list of strings and lists:

```
> aList = ['aaa', ['bbb', 'cc', 'd'], 'zz']
```

and here is how you convert it to a string:

```
> print str(aList)
['aaa', ['bbb', 'cc', 'd'], 'zz']
```

If you need something different, post a comment or update your question